# Join 2 tables and retrieve top X records in table2 for each record in table1 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to accomplish what seems a very simple task using Entity Framework. I have 2 tiny SQL tables: `Customers (Id, Name)` and `Orders (Id, CustomerId, DateTime)`. I need to get data from DB and display a table containing all customers and top 10 orders (or all of them if a customer has less than 10) for each customer.

It's obvious how to get the needed data the easy way: get all customers in 1 query (`var customers = dc.Customers.ToList()),` and then make a `foreach` loop to retrieve orders for each customer:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Customer, List<Order>>();
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
    dic.Add(customer, dc.Orders.Where(o => o.CustomerId == customer.Id).OrderBy(o => o.DateTime).Take(10).ToList();
}
```

But this way uses too many DB queries. How do I achieve the same result using only 1 query to the DB?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Dictionary<Customers, List<Orders>> dic = dc.Customers.Join(dc.Orders.OrderBy(o => o.DateTime).Take(10),
                            c => c.Id,
                            o => o.CustomerId,
                            (c, o) => new { Customers = c, Orders = o }
                            )
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Customers)
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y=>y.Orders)

                                                            .ToList());
```

**Left Join**

```
Dictionary<Customers, List<Orders>> dic = (from c in Customers
                                                      join o in Orders.OrderBy(o => o.DateTime).Take(10) on c.Id equals o.CustomerId into j1
                                                      from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                      group j2 by c into grouped
                                                      select new { Customers = grouped.Key, Orders = grouped.ToList() })
                                                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Customers, x => x.Orders);
```

Comment: Does this do a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: I'm looking at the generated SQL, and it seems to extract all joined records instead of top 10. Is there a way to extract TOP 10 on DB side rather than on client side?

Comment: I updated my answer. Now before takes top 10 after data joining

Comment: @AndreBorges check please

Comment: Your queries take top 10 orders from the whole DB and then join them with customers, which is not correct. I need to take 10 orders for each customer.